# Remove axis ticks but maintain grid for 3D plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently using the below code to develop a `3D` plot with `matplotlib`. However, when I try to remove the axis ticks from the plot, I can't seem to do it. I'm trying to maintain the grid in the plot at the same time. I've tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027061/matplotlib-3d-remove-axis-ticks-draw-upper-edge-border) for my example, but it doesn't seem to work even when I use the code provided.

```
x_total = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(30, 10, 3))
# plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8.8))
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6.8))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(x_total[0][:, 0], x_total[0][:, 1], x_total[0][:, 2], **plot_kws);
ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.zaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.grid(True)
```

Is it possible to remove the tick marks from the `x`, `y`, and `z` axis but maintain the grid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like setting parameters in 3D plots is a bit finicky - I'm also having issues figuring out a good way. Here's a workaround that I think looks reasonable, though it's clearly not perfect.

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(color='white')
```